# How to share only the demo in Codepen?

Tags: user-interface, codepen, presentation, demo, code-sharing

Whenever I open the Codepen links, I am shown this UI.

[image]

I want to share this with someone but without the code being shown on the UI since that irrelevant to the target person. I want share only the demo part of this snippet.

Is there a way to share only the demo in the Codepen? Like this.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer to this. There's an option to view the demo in full page view mode in the Change view option. We can share that url with `/full` at the end to see only the demo.

[image]

Thanks.